# Android scale animation not scaling from center

Tags: android, animation, pivot, scale, android-relativelayout

I have RelativeLayout which initially is inside another RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

it has also some children elements and it's visibility is initially set to gone (tried invisible and visible as well). I do also have scale animation, which I set on this login_form layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXScale="0.1"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%p"
        android:pivotY="50%p"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

The problem is, that it doesn't scale this layout from center, but from the right corner, even pivot point is specified as 50%p|50%p.
**When I change value to 25%p|25%p it does work**, but I don't know why?
I also scale other layouts with this animation, and they scale correctly from center, when pivot point is specified as 50%p|50%p. What is wrong with this relative layout?
Parent layout has nothing special in it, just specified width and height to MATCH_PARENT and no other attributes. I tried 50%|50%, also tried to do it programatically, but it just simply doesn't work until I set values to 25%|25%. It's happenning only with this RelativeLayout.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem.. Did you found a solution for this anomaly?

Comment: Not really, I actually target different devices differently. It seems it is and Android bug.